# How can I render a Carousel in R Shiny that has image and text with SlickR?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus, slickr

I'm working on a Shiny app to develop a test environment for a recommender system in the backend and I want to render some carousels to show the results of the recommender algorithms. I'm using a library called 'SlickR' that is very easy to use and the visual is pretty good, but i'm having some problems to render a carousel with text and image in shiny.

The thing is that when I render the carousel as I need it in a normal R Script, everything works fine, with the image and the text on the bottom and the horizontal scrolling working fine, just like this:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
library(slickR)

x <- slickR(obj = c("img_1","img_2","img_3","img_4","img_5","img_6","img_7","img_8"),
            slideType = 'p',
            height = 100) +
  settings(dots = TRUE,arrows = FALSE,slidesToShow = 3,slidesToScroll = 3)
y <- slickR(obj = sample(list.files(here::here("www/categories/"),
                                    full.names = TRUE)),
            height = 100) + 
  settings(dots = FALSE,slidesToShow = 3,slidesToScroll = 3)

y %synch% x
```

Pretty simple and everything looks good, but the thing is than when I wrap exactly the same code in a 'renderSlickR' object like this

```
      output$slick_output_1 <- renderSlickR({
    
    x <- slickR(obj = c("img_1","img_2","img_3","img_4","img_5","img_6","img_7","img_8"),slideType = 'p',height = 100) + 
      settings(dots = TRUE,arrows = FALSE,slidesToShow = 3,slidesToScroll = 3)
    y <- slickR(obj = sample(list.files(here::here("www/categories/"),full.names = TRUE)),height = 100) + 
      settings(dots = FALSE,slidesToShow = 3,slidesToScroll = 3)
      
    y %synch% x 
})
```

And send it to the ui with `box(slickROutput("slick_output_1"),title = "Reel 1",width = 12)` this happens:

[image]

The images don't show anymore and just the text render, but also, the carousel gets stuck and don't scroll to the left/right, the arrows at the sides do not render aswell.

The only option that worked for me in shiny is if I set the *dots* parameter to TRUE in the settings for both objects like this:

```
  output$slick_output_1 <- renderSlickR({
    
    #This works fine because dots is TRUE in the settings for both objects
    #but this code don't render the expected output
    
    x <- slickR(obj = c("img_1","img_2","img_3","img_4","img_5","img_6","img_7","img_8"),slideType = 'p',height = 100) +
      settings(dots = TRUE,arrows = FALSE,slidesToShow = 3,slidesToScroll = 3)
    y <- slickR(obj = sample(list.files(here::here("www/categories/"),full.names = TRUE)),height = 100) + 
      settings(dots = TRUE,slidesToShow = 3,slidesToScroll = 3)
      
    y %synch% x
  })
```

But the output is not the expected because it render the 2 carousel synched (one with the images and one with the text) but both with the (...) at the bottom to change the slides:

[image]

Any other combination of the *dots* parameter will result on a freeze of the carousel and in a unexpected outcome in shiny, the strange thing is that if the dots parameter remains TRUE, it will work, but it's not what we want, but if I run it in a normal R script, any combination work and all the outcomes render the carousels correctly.

For me it looks like a bug of the library when it is used with shiny, but i wanted to ask the community if someone had the same issue before, if we agree that it's a bug, or if i'm doing something wrong, or even if someone knows an alternative.

Any comments are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cause is the following one. The `slickR` function returns a HTML element with an id, and by default this id is `baseDiv`. So with your code you get two HTML elements having the same id, and this is not allowed in a HTML document. Therefore, if you provide two different id, with the `slideId` argument, that should work.

```r
library(shiny)
library(slickR)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  slickROutput("s")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$s <- renderSlickR({
    x <- slickR(obj = nba_player_logo$uri[1:3], slideId = "slick1")
    y <- slickR(obj = c("img1", "img2", "img3"), slideType = "p", slideId = "slick2")
    y %synch% x
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```